# PostgreSQL function for all rows in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, time, plpgsql

I have a table (called time_table) that has a column called "time". This column has timestamps in the following format:
2017-07-31 09:08:42

In other words:
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

I want to divide all these timestamps to an interval of five minutes. So, for example, 09:00:00 is one interval, 09:05:00 is another. The example above, would thus be placed be in the 2017-07-31 09:05:00 interval.

My plan for doing this is the following:

1. Convert timestamp to epoch time
2. Calculate epoch % 300
3. Subtract (epoch % 300) from epoch

Example:

2017-07-31 09:08:42 in epoch is 1501492122.

1501492122 % 300 = 222

1501492122 - 222 = 1501491900

1501491900 is converted to 2017-07-31 09:05:00. That is my interval.

I am trying to do this in PostgreSQL. I figured creating a function would be easiest. The first step can be calculated with

```
select extract('epoch' from time) from time_table
```

And that translated the timestamp correctly into epoch. But I have problems putting everything into one function. Right now I have implemented the following:

```
create or replace function stamp_to_epoch() returns table (epoch_mod integer) as $$
declare
epoch integer;
epoch_mod integer;
begin
select extract('epoch' from time) from time_table into epoch;
select (epoch % 300) into epoch_mod;
return query select (epoch - epoch_mod);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

This returns

```
stamp_to_epoch
----------------
    1501491900 
(1 row)
```

Which is correct, but not for all rows. In other words, it only returns one row even if I have multiple rows with different timestamps for clearly different intervals. My thought is that the function calculates the epoch interval for the very first timestamp, hence I only get one result. How should I make sure the function calculates this for every row?

I find it difficult understanding the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html) which is probably why I am having this problem. I have searched but think it is quite difficult to search for exactly what I am looking for.

**EDIT:**
I got asked to include table input and the expected output.

Table input (table: time_table):

```
 time         
----------------------
 2017-05-09 05:08:42 
 2017-05-10 05:16:24
 2017-07-31 09:08:42
```

Expected output:

```
 time         
----------------------
 2017-05-09 05:05:00 
 2017-05-10 05:15:00
 2017-07-31 09:05:00
```

Comment: Please include your table input data and the expected output.

Comment: why not `select extract('epoch' from time) - (extract('epoch' from time) % 300) from time_table`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun You are absolutely correct. Sometimes the brain is not thinking about solving it the easy way. Thank you, that works perfectly. Cannot really give your comment a "correct answer", but if I could, I would.

Comment: @hokosha I have put it as an answer, despite it would be more suitable as solution :)

Comment: The issue is that you are doing the query in the function. You should add a parameter to the function (the original time_stamp) and use it for conversion. You can then call the function with the relevant timestamp for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not answer the question, but following the code logic, you could just

```
select extract('epoch' from time) - (extract('epoch' from time) % 300) 
from time_table
```

with no function at all